# UpdateTargetId not working.(Ajax BeginForm)

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller

I want my table to be updated after inserting or making with Ajax BeginForm. but even though I give the id of the table to UpdateTargetId, it does not update my table and makes my table disappear. I am not getting any error in console.
Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Customers(Customers customers)
        {
            if (customers.crud_type == "insert")
            {
                ModelState.Remove("Customers.musteri_id");
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    try
                    {    
                        bool isSuccess = customerService.InsertCustomer(customers);
                        if (isSuccess)
                        {
                            return Json(new { result = true, message = "Müşteri başarıyla eklendi." });
                        }
                        .........
```

AjaxBeginForm:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Customers", "Customer", new AjaxOptions{HttpMethod = "POST",OnSuccess = "customerSuccess", UpdateTargetId = "tableContainer",InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}))
```

And I also added `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>`library.